# C# retrieve Received and Sent Bytes with TraceEvent - Network Activity for own .exe not working

Tags: c#

I'm building a small tool for me.
I wanted to retrieve only Bytes Received and Bytes Sent from my exe.

This is working code for "chrome", but if i change "chrome" with my executable file name (example: this is my bot) then it isnt working. The exe process gets found with the correct ID, but nothing more, its not counting ( 0 bytes both sides)...

And yes, the Code is running with Admin rights.

Edit: the code is running inside of my tool, so not a second exe.

```
internal static int received = 0;
internal static int sent = 0;

public static async Task test()
{
    var counterLock = new object();

    var processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome").Select(p => p.Id).ToHashSet();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var session = new TraceEventSession("MyKernelAndClrEventsSession"))
        {
            session.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.NetworkTCPIP);

            session.Source.Kernel.TcpIpRecv += data =>
            {
                if (processList.Contains(data.ProcessID))
                    lock (counterLock)
                        received += data.size;
            };
            session.Source.Kernel.TcpIpSend += data =>
            {
                if (processList.Contains(data.ProcessID))
                    lock (counterLock)
                        sent += data.size;
            };
            session.Source.Kernel.UdpIpRecv += data =>
            {
                if (processList.Contains(data.ProcessID))
                    lock (counterLock)
                        received += data.size;
            };
            session.Source.Kernel.UdpIpSend += data =>
            {
                if (processList.Contains(data.ProcessID))
                    lock (counterLock)
                        sent += data.size;
            };

            session.Source.Process();
        }
    });

    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        lock (counterLock)
            Console.WriteLine($"Sent: {sent.ToString("N0")} bytes    Received: {received.ToString("N0")} bytes");
    }
}
```

What is wrong and why is my code not working for my own exe file but it works for other exe files like chrome?

Working for Chrome: Sent: 425 bytes    Received: 80’750 bytes

Comment: I know you mention your code is running with admin rights, but have you verified if your bot is running as a process while you execute this program? Also, have you verified the process name matches what you're inserting into Process.GetProcessesByName()?

Comment: @cdbullard if i understand correct, yes. The Code is running inside my Bot, so no other exe, just one, my Tool and inside that tool that Code. And yes, the programm name get found by the correct id with Process.GetProcessesByName().